# How to write efficient type bounded code if the types are unrelated in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I want to improve the following Cassandra related Scala code. I have two unrelated [user defined types](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/crudOperations.html) which are actually in Java source files (leaving out the details).

```
public class Blob { .. }
public class Meta { .. }
```

So here is how I use them currently from Scala:

```
private val blobMapper: Mapper[Blob] = mappingManager.mapper(classOf[Blob])
private val metaMapper: Mapper[Meta] = mappingManager.mapper(classOf[Meta])

def save(entity: Object) = {
  entity match {
    case blob: Blob => blobMapper.saveAsync(blob)
    case meta: Meta => metaMapper.saveAsync(meta)
    case _ => // exception
 }
}
```

While this works, how can you avoid the following problems

1. repetition when adding new user defined type classes like `Blob` or `Meta`
2. pattern matching repetition when adding new methods like `save`
3. having `Object` as parameter type

Comment: Making them extend a common trait is not an option?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that typeclass would be a good solution here.

Comment: Common (marker) Interface (Blob and Meta are Java) is an option yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely use `Mapper` as a typeclass, doing:

```
def save[A](entity: A)(implicit mapper: Mapper[A]) = mapper.saveAsync(entity)
```

Now you have a generic method able to perform a save operation on every type `A` for which a `Mapper[A]` is in scope.

Also, the `mappingManager.mapper` implementation could be probably improved to avoid `classOf`, but it's hard to tell from the question in the current state.

Comment: Looks good. Is there a way to use a Map of all Mappers instead for having them in the implicit scope individually?

Comment: you mean `Map` as a data structure? I'd say no, as the type system wouldn't have enough information to retrieve all the mappers. You could always use an `implicit def` macro to generate them, but it won't give you great benefits I'm afraid

Comment: to clarify, if you have a `Map[String, Mapper[_]]` the type system only knows that you have a bunch of mappers in there, but it can't know that you specifically have - say - a `Mapper[Blob]`. And that's because standard collections are monomorphic in scala.

Comment: yes some `scala.collection.Map` but I like your solution even without this :)

Answer (score 1):

A few questions:

- Is `mappingManager.mapper(cls)` expensive?
- How much do you care about handling subclasses of Blob or Meta?

Can something like this work for you?

```
def save[T: Manifest](entity: T) = {
  mappingManager.mapper(manifest[T].runtimeClass).saveAsync(entity)
}
```

If you do care about making sure that subclasses of Meta grab the proper mapper then you may find `isAssignableFrom` helpful in your `.mapper` (and store found sub-classes in a HashMap so you only have to look once).

EDIT: Then maybe you want something like this (ignoring threading concerns):

```
private[this] val mapperMap = mutable.HashMap[Class[_], Mapper[_]]()
def save[T: Manifest](entity: T) = {
  val cls = manifest[T].runtimeClass
  mapperMap.getOrElseUpdate(cls, mappingManager.mapper(cls))
    .asInstanceOf[Mapper[T]]
    .saveAsync(entity)
}
```

Comment: It's somewhat expensive since it will be called often. If possible I'd like to do it just once and keep the returns value in a Map. Subclasses are not used.

Comment: `asInstanceOf` does a cast or (reflection)? Otherwise exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @reikje `asInstanceOf` is a cast. Keeping in mind that using reflection is more expensive (and less idiomatic). If you can use static typing (perhaps using a proper type class) for the same purpose, I'd much recommend it.

Comment: It's difficult to get around casting if your saveAsync method takes a specific T and you're pulling the mapper out of a map. It's not possible to say that the key and values must be of the same generic type -- so the cast has to occur someplace (if you're not going to go with the compile-time solution provided by Gabriele).